# How to disable to ngbDropdown so that User can not change the value

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap

We are having ngb dropdown such as below

```
<div ngbDropdown class="d-inline-block" >
  <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="dropdownMenu1" ngbDropdownToggle>Toggle dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <button class="dropdown-item">Action - 1</button>
    <button class="dropdown-item">Another Action</button>
    <button class="dropdown-item">Something else is here</button>
  </div>
```

Somehow we tried attaching the [disabled]="true" but is not disabling.
Any other way or how to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Put your code inside ng-container to disable it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The `disabled` attribute should be added to the element where `ngbDropdownToggle` directive is used — it will disable the trigger